# WMI with Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, wmi, event-log

I like to get the last entry from SystemEventLog with EventCode 6006. With this Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile='System' AND EventCode='6006'
```

I get **all** the 6006 Events in the SystemEventLog.
I've already tried LIMIT 1, LAST.

Is there a way to get **only the last SystemEventLog entry with code 6006**?

Thanks

Comment: Did `LIMIT 1` not return just one result? Why didn't it work? Do you need to order by timestamp?

Comment: LIMIT 1 returns the error: (-2147217385, 'OLE error 0x80041017', None, None)

Comment: Please update the question with what command you have tried, what output you expect and what output you actually get..